# Bootstrap columns overlapping on small screens

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 2 columns and on the left and the right side, When I open the web page on a small or xs screen the two columns overlap. I would like for the other column to go below the other.

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3"></div>
      <div class="col-md-9 area-style"></div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.area-style {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding-top: 2em;
  background: #fafafa;
  height: 500px;
}
```

Comment: Please add area-style style (CSS) so we can help you

Comment: Add full code to look upon so that we can check for issue.

Comment: No it shouldn't , but if you add style like position or float on area-style then it will affect.. Please better to post css and html both here

Comment: Please share a JSFiddle link of the code snippet

Comment: <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"></div>
      <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 area-style"></div>
    </div>
 </div> no need of area-style class

Comment: What version of bootstrap are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Please check if you have given floats to the elements inside any of the "col-md-3" or "col-md-9" divs. The Overlapping 99% occurs If the floats are not cleared.

Comment: In my case it was a button I had in the div that I had a float right on (I even did it using the bootstrap pull-right class) and this caused the issue. Removing it on a mobile solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Bootstrap4 try this.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-3"></div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-9 area-style"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-9 area-style"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please tell me if this helps you.